# certificate issues certificate authority c#

Tags: c#, certificate

In C# our maintainance project, we observered that the previous company has a root certificate. This certificate is valid in domain only, for 2020. How can they create such a root certificate free. Can anyone guide us.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone can create a certificate using [Makecert.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(VS.80).aspx). But it obviously won't be from a trusted authority.

You can manage certificates with [certmgr.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I believe GoDaddy issues generic certificates (we have one here).  They cost a little more, but cover the sub-domains.

If you are asking for how to do it for free.  You need to set up a certificate server (or use makecert like Mitch said if you don't care about a trusted certificate), and become a certificate authority (I don't mean like GoDaddy etc., although they are one).  To get people to accept the certificate, you need them to trust the authority.